# How to set the contextConfigLocation file value in Spring when it's not inside WEB-INF folder?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-security

```
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/
```

In this tutorial he sets the value of `contextConfigLocation` as `/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml`. All the tutorials of spring security I've found online use /WEB-INF as if was the root folder even though it isn't, it's usually inside another folder ( in my case called `web`).

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

My project doesn't have a WEB-INF folder but I still need to set param-value to my xml ( called applicationContext.xml in the path myProject/conf/admin ) , but when I just set the value like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /admin/applicationContext.xml
        /admin/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/admin/applicationContext.xml]
```

What do I put inside param-value to point to the correct location of my xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by reading build.xml to see where Ant was putting the files inside /myProject/conf/admin when building the war and it turns out it was in the WEB-INF/config folder, through a zipfileset, so all I had to do was point the contextConfigLocation in web.xml to /WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give classpath reference for `<param-value>`

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
    classpath:admin/applicationContext.xml
    classpath:admin/applicationContext-security.xml
</param-value>
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that didn't help. It's still throwing the exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [admin/applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: Can you please provide full path of  applicationContext.xml in your project ? It should be working if admin/applicationContext.xml is in resources directory.

Comment: Sure, it's in /myProject/conf/admin/applicationContext.xml and web.xml is in /myProject/conf/admin/web.xml. applicationContext-security.xml is also in the same folder.

Comment: If it's in java package then try 'classpath:conf/admin/applicationContext.xml' .It's Always a good practice to keep configuration files under resources.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found the solution and answered my own question.